# Dot product in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dot-product

I have two data frames in Spark Scala where the second column of each data frame is an array of numbers

```
val data22= Seq((1,List(0.693147,0.6931471)),(2,List(0.69314, 0.0)),(3,List(0.0, 0.693147))).toDF("ID","tf_idf")
data22.show(truncate=false)

+---+---------------------+
|ID |tf_idf               |
+---+---------------------+
|1  |[0.693, 0.702]       |
|2  |[0.69314, 0.0]       |
|3  |[0.0, 0.693147]      |
+---+---------------------+



val data12= Seq((1,List(0.69314,0.6931471))).toDF("ID","tf_idf")
data12.show(truncate=false)

+---+--------------------+
|ID |tf_idf              |
+---+--------------------+
|1  |[0.693, 0.805]      |
+---+--------------------+
```

I need to perform the **dot product between rows** in this two data frames. That is I need to multiply the `tf_idf` array in `data12` with each row of `tf_idf` in `data22`.

(Ex: The first row in dot product should be like this  : 0.693*0.693 + 0.702*0.805

Second row : 0.69314*0.693 + 0.0*0.805

Third row : 0.0*0.693 + 0.693147*0.805 )

Basically I want something(like matrix multiplication) `data22`*`transpose(data12)` 
I would be grateful if someone can suggest a method to do this in Spark Scala .

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is shown below:

```
scala> val data22= Seq((1,List(0.693147,0.6931471)),(2,List(0.69314, 0.0)),(3,List(0.0, 0.693147))).toDF("ID","tf_idf")
data22: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: int, tf_idf: array<double>]

scala> val data12= Seq((1,List(0.69314,0.6931471))).toDF("ID","tf_idf")
data12: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [ID: int, tf_idf: array<double>]

scala> val arrayDot = data12.take(1).map(row => (row.getAs[Int](0), row.getAs[WrappedArray[Double]](1).toSeq))
arrayDot: Array[(Int, Seq[Double])] = Array((1,WrappedArray(0.69314, 0.6931471)))

scala> val dotColumn = arrayDot(0)._2
dotColumn: Seq[Double] = WrappedArray(0.69314, 0.6931471)

scala> val dotUdf = udf((y: Seq[Double]) => y zip dotColumn map(z => z._1*z._2) reduce(_ + _))
dotUdf: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>,DoubleType,Some(List(ArrayType(DoubleType,false))))

scala> data22.withColumn("dotProduct", dotUdf('tf_idf)).show
+---+--------------------+-------------------+
| ID|              tf_idf|         dotProduct|
+---+--------------------+-------------------+
|  1|[0.693147, 0.6931...|   0.96090081381841|
|  2|      [0.69314, 0.0]|0.48044305959999994|
|  3|     [0.0, 0.693147]|    0.4804528329237|
+---+--------------------+-------------------+
```

Note that it multiplies multiply the `tf_idf` array in `data12` with each row of `tf_idf` in `data22`.

Let me know if it helps!!

Answer (score 7):

**Spark Version 2.4+:** Use the several functions for array such as `zip_with` and `aggregate`, that give you more simpler code. To follow your detailed description, I have changed the `join` into `crossJoin`.

```
val data22= Seq((1,List(0.693147,0.6931471)),(2,List(0.69314, 0.0)),(3,List(0.0, 0.693147))).toDF("ID","tf_idf")
val data12= Seq((1,List(0.693,0.805))).toDF("ID2","tf_idf2")

val df = data22.crossJoin(data12).drop("ID2")
df.withColumn("DotProduct", expr("aggregate(zip_with(tf_idf, tf_idf2, (x, y) -> x * y), 0D, (sum, x) -> sum + x)")).show(false)
```

Here is the result.

```
+---+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+
|ID |tf_idf               |tf_idf2       |DotProduct         |
+---+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+
|1  |[0.693147, 0.6931471]|[0.693, 0.805]|1.0383342865       |
|2  |[0.69314, 0.0]       |[0.693, 0.805]|0.48034601999999993|
|3  |[0.0, 0.693147]      |[0.693, 0.805]|0.557983335        |
+---+---------------------+--------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer . But this is not something i want. You might misunderstood my question. I am sorry for the confusion. I updated the question so please have a look.

Comment: @Sam88, I have modified the answer.